# If $A+B+C=180°$, prove that: $\sin^3 A+....$

Tags: trigonometry

If $A+B+C=180°$, prove that:
$$\sin^3 A+ sin^3 B+ sin^3 C= 3cos(\frac {A}{2}). cos(\frac {B}{2}). cos(\frac {C}{2})+ cos(\frac {3A}{2}.cos(\frac {3B}{2}). cos(\frac {3C}{2})$$.

My Attempt:

Given,
$A+B+C=180$.

Now,

$$L.H.S=sin^3 A+ sin^3 B+sin^3 C$$
$$=\frac {3sinA-sin3A}{4}+\frac {3sinB-sin3B}{4}+\frac {3sinC-sin3C}{4}$$.
$$=\frac {1}{4} [3sinA+3sinB+3sinC-sin3A-sin3B-sin3C]$$.-
$$=\frac {3}{4} [sinA+sinB+sinC] - \frac {1}{4} [sin3A+sin3B+sin3C]$$.

Please help me to complete the proof

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have done the tougher part.

Now  use [Prosthaphaeresis Formula](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ProsthaphaeresisFormulas.html),

$$\sin A+\sin B+\sin C=2\sin\dfrac{A+B}2\cos\dfrac{A-B}2+2\sin\dfrac C2\cos\dfrac C2$$

Use replacement for

$\sin\dfrac{A+B}2=\sin\dfrac{\pi-C}2=\cos\dfrac C2$

and $\sin\dfrac C2=\cdots=\cos\dfrac{A+B}2$

Simialrly, $$\sin3A+\sin3B+\sin3C=2\sin\dfrac{3(A+B)}2\cos\dfrac{3(A-B)}2+2\sin\dfrac{3C}2\cos\dfrac{3C}2$$

Use replacement for

$\sin\dfrac{3(A+B)}2=\sin\dfrac{3(\pi-C)}2=\sin\left(\pi+\dfrac\pi2-\dfrac{3C}2\right)=\cdots=-\cos\dfrac{3C}2$

and $\sin\dfrac{3C}2=\cdots=-\cos\dfrac{3(A+B)}2$

Comment: what would be the simpler part, then?

Comment: @user354073, Please pinpoint your confusion in the answer.

Comment: @ Lab, I meant to say that.  You said that I have done the tougher part. But what would be the simpler way?

Comment: @user354073, I didn't say you did in a tougher way